# Oil Says Empty, Dipstick clean, but just changed it all?! 1998 Merc Benz ML320

Tags: oil, mercedes-benz, ml320

Had an issue come up yesterday where my Truck (1998 Mercedes Benz ML320) just suddenly said no oil and then started pinging a little then cut off. I threw a quart in ( i always keep one in the truck) and made it home with no more complaint UNTIL I got to my house, it cut off again and said no oil.

Today I changed the oil. The oil pan overflowed it was so full! ??? Ok, odd, put cork bolt back in after changing filter, and put in 4.5q of new, fresh oil. I've checked a 100 times over, nothing is leaking out, but my dip stick is clean!? I even climbed back under and pulled the bolt out of the oil pan, sure enough, squirted with fresh, clear (yellow/green tinted) oil.

So I thought, wth?! I'm no mechanic but figured, maybe it just needs to run a little. I drove a quarter mile and back. 2wice the oil light cut on, then cut off shortly after. The 3rd times it stayed on till i finally cut the truck off. I got out, waited a few, checked the dipstick. Still clean!?

How is it i can have a pan full of oil, fresh filter and all, and still get no oil reading on BOTH the electric sensor and the manual dipstick?! I'm so confused.

And I reiterate, there is NOTHING leaking anywhere that I can see. There is no foam in the radiator fluid, no puddles under the truck, no oil on any of the motor. I just don't get it.  Oh and the little knock is gone, but I have to drive an hour a day for work, on the interstate, (70mph speed limit). I can't afford to break down and have no one to call on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I might be stupid. Should have checked around more. Checked around online, as I had before, but this time found a yahoo answer I had not seen before. `"'98-'03 ML320 which would make it a gasoline engine and it uses 8 L or 8.5 quarts. "`. Looks like I far underestimated how much oil this beast uses. Guess I'll oil it up some more and hope for the best.

Comment: Yes, the 5 quart oil change is a thing of the past for many cars, not just your Mercedes. This is one of the reasons you can go further between oil changes in them. Thanks for posting your answer, and don't forget to select it as the answer.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks, and I will when I can (2day thing). Learning of this the hard way definitely scared me. First vehicle I've owned made after 1992!

Comment: Meh, 8 quarts pales into insignificance when you consider the **13 l** needed by 12-cylinder Touaregs ;)